# Is there a hardware temperature sensor indicator?

Tags: unity, indicator, sensors

Well, just like the title says : is there any hardware sensors indicator so i can add it to unity's panel?

I only found applets for the older gnome panel.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/15832/62483

Comment: I'm puzzled as to how to switch any of these mentioned indicators on (how to put them onto the panel) after I have installed them. Could someone perhaps give an advice?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I'm working on one at the moment ([indicator-sensors](https://launchpad.net/indicator-sensors)) which with any luck will be ready in time for the final release of natty - code is barely functional at the moment and still need to figure out a bunch of UI issues, so will be a week or two at least until anything release worthy is finished.

Comment: upvote for the effort! i'm looking forward to having temp sensors (and fans speed?) in natty.

Comment: Cool! can we help with the testing part?

Comment: For sure - feel free to check the code out and compile and test it - although at the moment it is quite feature incomplete but will provide rudimentary support - new features etc should be added pretty quickly so keep watching :)

Comment: A quick update - have released an initial alpha version (covered on webupd8 http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/indicator-sensors-displays-cpu.html) and have an official PPA here: https://launchpad.net/~alexmurray/+archive/indicator-sensors

Comment: How to install it with apt-get?

Comment: [It's a pity](http://askubuntu.com/q/449898/19753) that neither of `indicator-sysmonitor` and `indicator-sensors` packages is present in 14.04 (Trusty) repositories (unlike `psesnsor`), so that I could check all them out. Are there plans to put them in the Ubuntu repositories for any later Ubuntu release?

Answer (score 11):

The cpu and memory indicator now supports temperature sensors too. Check [indicator-sysmonitor](https://launchpad.net/indicator-sysmonitor)

Comment: [It's a pity](http://askubuntu.com/q/449898/19753) that neither of `indicator-sysmonitor` and `indicator-sensors` packages is present in 14.04 (Trusty) repositories (unlike `psesnsor`), so that I could check all them out. Are there plans to put them in the Ubuntu repositories for any later Ubuntu release?

Answer (score 4):

Psensors has temp indicators.

Add ppa:jfi/ppa to your repositories (or just add nothing if are on 15.04 (Vivid) or later) and then install psensor (and its dependents) in Synaptic.

`psensor` can show the real temperature values in the top bar only since version 1.0.2 according to http://wpitchoune.net/blog/sensors-in-the-top-bar-of-the-desktop/ (via https://askubuntu.com/a/452501/19753).

That's why one used to have to add an extra PPA to get this feature.

This feature is included in the Ubuntu repositories **since 15.04 (Vivid)**. And earlier Ubuntu releases, for instance, 14.04 (Trusty), has psensor-0.8.0.3 in the repositories (without this feature).

Comment: psensors have already been mentioned, if i recall correctly

Comment: `psensor` can show the real temperature values in the top bar only since version 1.0.2 according to  http://wpitchoune.net/blog/sensors-in-the-top-bar-of-the-desktop/ (via http://askubuntu.com/a/452501/19753 ). This feature is included in the Ubuntu repositories **since 15.04 (Vivid)**. And earlier Ubuntu releases, for instance, 14.04 (Trusty), has psensor-0.8.0.3 in the repositories (without this feature).

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite fond of screenlets

add to desktop rather than panel though;

sensors screenlets seem nice, there are more similar;

work in unity although possibly not in gnome-shell; need sensors too

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors screenlets screenlets-pack-all
```

Comment: As an even simpler workaround for the wish to always see the temperatures I'm running `xsensors` and switch on the "always on top" property of the window.