# Sensors applet (temperature) for Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: unity, temperature, sensors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a hardware temperature sensor indicator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33976/is-there-a-hardware-temperature-sensor-indicator)

Hi everyone!
In oldest versions of Ubuntu I used sensors applet that shows temperature of my Hard disk and Processor on my panel.
In Ubuntu 11.04 I cant use that. So, is there something for unity maybe that will show me the temperature? Or is there another way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: On my HP laptop, the old temperature sensor has stopped working even under "Ubuntu Classic".