# Why is my Laptop shutting down when playing The Sims 3?

Tags: nvidia, wine

Whenever I try to play The Sims 3 using Wine 1.2 in Ubuntu Natty the Acer Aspire 4935G is just shutting down without any warning. According to appdb.winehq.org The Sims 3 should work almost perfectly fine (Gold status) on Ubuntu and as long as the laptop does not turn off everything does work fine.

I also tried different graphics drivers but NVIDIA current worked best for the GeForce 9300M GS. When the laptop is shutting down while I'm playing The Sims 3 I found the following messages (amongst others) in `jokey.log`:

```
2011-08-14 10:52:28,537 DEBUG: nvidia.available: falling back to default
2011-08-14 10:52:28,745 DEBUG: nvidia_173 is not the alternative in use
2011-08-14 10:52:31,054 DEBUG: nvidia_173 is not the alternative in use
2011-08-14 10:52:31,113 DEBUG: nvidia_173 is not the alternative in use
2011-08-14 10:52:40,779 DEBUG: Shutting down
```

I couldn't find any errors in `kern.log`, `Xorg.0.log` or `syslog`. But maybe I didn't look at the right place?

Activating metacity for the time the game is played seems to increase the time I can run the game before the laptop is shutting down.

I also noticed that the fans were runing very loud during the whole time the game is played. Maybe the laptop is overheating? How can I check if this is the case?

Comment: suggest install a temperature monitor such as this to see what temperature your laptop is reaching: http://askubuntu.com/questions/33976/is-there-a-hardware-temperature-sensor-indicator

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your computer is most likely shutting down unexpectedly because either the kernel or BIOS thinks it's in imminent danger, usually due to overheating issues.  There may be a faulty driver, or perhaps you have a broken fan but don't notice the heat buildup unless you tax the system by running Wine.  There could be another sort of cooling problem as well, such as a lack of (or too much) thermal paste.

While Wine's the proximate cause here, this isn't really Wine's fault - it's exposing a deeper problem in the system.