# How to add a temperature indicator to the panel?

Tags: 11.04, macbook, sensors

I have installed the `sensors-applet` using the terminal line: `sudo apt-get install sensors-applet`.

but there is no applet in the list of applets when I right-click on the gnome-panel.

I am using Ubuntu Natty on a MacBook Pro.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/33976/is-there-a-hardware-temperature-sensor-indicator

Comment: sensors-applet is an applet for Gnome-2.x panel. You need to either whitelist it, or find an indicator compatible with Unity panel

Comment: 11.04 (Natty) is the first Ubuntu release to use Unity as the user interface, and not Gnome. So the question is about a temperature indicator for Unity, the same question as http://askubuntu.com/questions/33976/is-there-a-hardware-temperature-sensor-indicator .

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Psensor is available on the Ubuntu repositories since Oneiric.

For other Ubuntu versions, you can install it using a PPA. You will find the installation instruction in the [Ubuntu dedicated page of the Psensor website](http://wpitchoune.net/blog/psensor/ubuntu-integration/)

Answer (score 0):

Install Psensor from the Software Center.

Comment: 0. Why psensor? | 1.Why is the applet not showing in the list? | 2. Error: Unable to locate package psensor.

Comment: It appears that [Psensor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/psensor/) is only available for 11.10 and later.