# CPU temperature monitor for 14.04LTS?

Tags: 14.04, indicator, cpu, temperature

Is there a way to configure psensor so the temperatures read out in real time in the panel so it could be read at a glance? So far, in order to read the temperature I have to click on the applet indicator.
On 12.04 I had a Hardware Indicator Sensors by Alex Murray that did that job fine but it doesn't work in 14.04 (can anyone verify? I'm getting an "E: Unable to locate package indicator-sensors"). I ended up starting to use psensor again and it only shows the temp in Unity (my Unity is on auto hide).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a hardware temperature sensor indicator?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33976/is-there-a-hardware-temperature-sensor-indicator)

Comment: 11.04 (Natty) is the first Ubuntu release to use Unity as the user interface, and not Gnome. So the question is about a temperature indicator for Unity, the same question as http://askubuntu.com/questions/33976/is-there-a-hardware-temperature-sensor-indicator

Comment: I think this thread is outdated. I cannot duplicate anymore such a problem with psensor in 14.04. I think the packages listed in the answers should not be used. The default deps `lm-sensors hddtemp psensor` work better.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

See http://wpitchoune.net/blog/sensors-in-the-top-bar-of-the-desktop/.

It has been added in psensor since the release 1.0.2.

Basically, with a terminal:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jfi/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install psensor
```

Comment: Wow, it looks great. I can't wait. The nice thing about psensor is the notification alarms. Yeah, I could run indicator-sensors and psensor at the same time but I tend to like a cleaner panel.

Comment: you **dont** need to add **ppa** on Ubuntu **15.04**

Comment: It has a GUI as well. Great answer. +1

Comment: psensor is a great tool, it should be the accepted answer

Comment: How do I get the temperatures to show up in the bar like the screenshot in the link has?

Comment: simbabque That is a so-called experimental setting you find in Sensor Preferences (not the main Preferences dialog), in the "Application Indicator" tab.

Answer (score 16):

Try this: Go to your Dash and open Software and Updates. Go the other software tab and try to add it from there by pressing add. Add "ppa:alexmurray/indicator-sensors-daily" excluding the quotes and add. Check the box next to the source in the list of sources. Open a terminal and try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-sensors
```

If that doesnt work, try to install it from Synaptic Package Manager.
(To get it): `sudo apt-get install synaptic`
Open Synaptic and search indicator-sensors. Right click on it and click Mark For Installation. Click Apply and let it install.

Comment: I'm getting an "E: Unable to locate package indicator-sensors".

Comment: I updated the post, try again.

Comment: I just now got the same E:unable to locate

Comment: I tried it with the updated post too. Same thing.

Comment: Try this. I updated it again.

Comment: "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexmurray/indicator-sensors-daily" does work and it does show up in the Software & Updates under Other Software. The install results in an Unable to locate.

Manually adding the ppa in the Software and Updates is a no go either. Don't you need an http location? just adding "ppa:alexmurray/indicator-sensors-daily" does nothing and won't show up on the list or in Synaptics

Comment: Try this then: I went into my apt cache and took the deb file for the indicator-sensors package. Install this deb from here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/xbpy1zh8q0hm9to/indicator-sensors_0.7-1_amd64.deb?dl=1&token_hash=AAGl7nkz_JS6Uy3PDEaWkYpq8Jw9AV5Hn5f1nOxn9lfFMQ

Comment: I'm having the same problems as the OP. Something is wrong with that ppa. All other ppa:s work for me.

Comment: The deb you provided is the saucy version from ppa:alexmurray/indicator-sensors/, I think, not the trusty version from ppa:alexmurray/indicator-sensors-daily/.

Comment: If you check "view package details" at ppa:alexmurray/indicator-sensors-daily/ you'll see that the trusty package did not build properly.

Comment: So.. is there any update? I'm still getting "E: Unable to locate package indicator-sensors" from the daily ppa on 14.04

Comment: I used the deb file as provided in trusty it is working fine.

Comment: Alex Murray has kindly updated his ppa and the trusty package is now available at https://launchpad.net/~alexmurray/+archive/indicator-sensors-daily