# Does Ubuntu shutoff during overheat?

Tags: overheating

Does Ubuntu utilize the sensors on hardware such as the CPU to detect critical heat levels and shut off like the default OS would?

In this case the hardware is a Mac Mini.

Answer (score 1):

The default install of Ubuntu does NOT monitor your motherboard's temperature sensors.

Overheat-detection, and the resulting poweroff, is handled by the BIOS (or equivalent), not the OS. It is a last-defense from damage caused by the overheat.

Ubuntu can detect and use those temperature sensor readings, but the software is not included with a normal install. It's just a click away, in Software Center.

Example: The 'psensor' package (available in Software Center) can use those readings to preserver historical temperature data, create graphs, and trigger handy alerts so you have time so save your data before BIOS kills the power.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. Even if it doesn't your BIOS will shut the computer down. If you have overheating issues, most probably you haven't installed GPU drivers or your fan is not functioning. You can read the heat sensor like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449898/cpu-temperature-monitor-for-14-04lts).