# How to get temperature indicators in the panel in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, indicator, temperature

I was formerly using 10.04, where I had nice temperature indicators for my dual core like this :

[image: ubuntu 10.04 panel]

I am now trying to have the same feature with 14.04, but I haven't succeeded yet.
I tried so far :

- indicator-sensors, which showed only one core's temp (also, couldn't get it to launch on start-up)
- psensor, but somehow I have to click on it in order to read the temp.

Am I misusing these tools ? Is there an indicator that will launch at start-up and show my two cores' temp ?

Comment: Are you looking for these indicators?

[Indicators][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available

Comment: 11.04 (Natty) is the first Ubuntu release to use Unity as the user interface, and not Gnome. So the question is about a temperature indicator **for Unity**, the same question as http://askubuntu.com/questions/33976/is-there-a-hardware-temperature-sensor-indicator .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

since psensor v1.0.1, the value of the sensors can be displayed in the top bar, see https://wpitchoune.net/psensor/ubuntu.html

You can easily upgrade to a version of psensor including this new feature by using the psensor ppa:

> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jfi/ppa
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install psensor

Comment: There is now an updated Ubuntu page for psensor: https://wpitchoune.net/psensor/ubuntu.html

Answer (score 6):

Extending on JeanFI's answer.

Showing the temperature or fan speed on the top bar is an experimental feature even in v1.0.1.  Hence it is not enabled by default.  You got to do the following to get it displayed on the top bar.  For completeness, I am copy pasting JeanFi's answer here.

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jfi/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install psensor

launch psensor

[It will show as a small thermometer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwwPo.png)

click on the thermometer and select Sensor Preferences.

Select the needed metric on the left panel.  Go to the last tab "Application Indicator" and then select "Display sensor in the label".

you can do this for as many metrics as needed.  I set my fan and physical id to display their rpm and temperature.

[enabling display sensor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kaux8.png)

Answer (score 3):

I've been using psensor in Ubuntu 20.04 and I can see these information as in the image below.

[image]

Install it with `sudo apt install psensor` then run searching it in the ubuntu apps, then go to `Sensor Preferences` menu, select the CPU's temperature in the left side (or other information) and check the `Display sensor in the label`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you already installed `sensors` and `sensors-detect` was run then
you can install `sensors-applet` and `reboot` to get them in panel.