# How do I add the System Monitor applet to Unity?

Tags: unity, applet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can replace system monitoring in the top Gnome Panel in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29757/what-can-replace-system-monitoring-in-the-top-gnome-panel-in-unity)

Prior to using Unity, I had several Gnome Panel Applets running in a panel. I used the Dictionary applet, and the System Monitor applet, among others. While the general "systray" area has been replaced by the "indicator" area, and my Gnome Panel Launchers were migrated to Unity Launchers, there doesn't seem to be an analogy to the more general "Panel Applets" from the prior Gnome UI. I can live without the Dictionary applet, but none of the system monitors written for the Indicator Area are nearly as useful and complete as the System Monitor Applet from the Gnome Panel. How do I get that applet running within my Unity environment?

Comment: Can someone put a link to the duplicate?, as I can not find it.