# Is there a process indicator for Unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity, indicator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can replace system monitoring in the top Gnome Panel in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29757/what-can-replace-system-monitoring-in-the-top-gnome-panel-in-unity)

Hi!

I have just upgraded to the 11.04 Ubuntu beta and am trying to get used to Unity. Seems good so far, but I really miss having the Gnome process monitor at the top panel. (Really useful when running long compilations/testing since it is usually enough to glance at it to see if everything is going as it should.)

Is there any substitute in Unity?

Comment: Please ask a separate question for the disk mounter, that way we can group all the indicator questions together, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, it does indeed seem to be a dupe of that question. Got some more suggestions there that I will check out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Jorge retagged my question as "indicator" I found the following page which lists some replacements for old applets:

[What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/list-of-appindicators)

Unfortunately not all of them are available for natty yet, but at least I got a very basic system load monitor (indicator-sysmonitor) and a weather indicator (indicator-weather) working.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the gnome process monitor.  However I'm aware of the following [application indicator](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/08/indicator-monitor-puts-system-stressing-process-in-plain-sight/) which you can use display process usage of running applications.

Since the developer of the ppa doesnt have a natty version I did the following to get the application to work

```
sudo dpkg -i indicator-monitor_0.1.0-1_i386.deb
cd /usr/lib
sudo ln -s libappindicator.so.1.0.0 libappindicator.so.0
sudo ln -s libdbus-glib-1.so.2.1.0 libdbus-glib-1.so.1
sudo ln -s libdbusmenu-glib.so.3.0.14 libdbusmenu-glib.so.1
indicator-monitor &
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in 11.04 beta unfortunately. It refuses to start because it cant find libappindicator.so.0. Synaptic refuses to get libappindicator0, so I guess it's due to missing dependencies.

Comment: ok - I've edited the reply above on how to get this working under natty

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing, so far as I can see, but there is one way to get a somewhat more classic design of Ubuntu that will allow you to use one. Log out of your account. Click or enter your username (depending on whether you have hidden the user list or not) and then look at the bottom of the screen. There are 3 menus, and one of them probably says something like "Ubuntu" or "Ubuntu Desktop". Open this menu, and then click "Ubuntu Desktop Classic". (This may not be exactly what it says, but it's close) Now enter your password and log in. You will see a somewhat familiar Ubuntu desktop. **ONE DIFFERENCE YOU DO NOT WANT TO MISS:** The menus are integrated into the top panel like in Unity, but the title bar does not merge. Don't try and put the old tri-menu start button replacement in, because you will have menus from your open apps mixed in with them. (Example: Applications Places SystemFile Edit View Tools)

Once you have that, just use Ubuntu and the Gnome Panel like you would in 10.10. All of the options to add applets are still there.

Hope that is what you are looking for.

Comment: The menu isn't integrated into the panel anymore