# How can I configure the system monitor indicator (indicator-sysmonitor)?

Tags: indicator

I'm settling for the system monitor indicator (indicator-sysmonitor) for now since there doesn't seem to be any good alternative (for natty) at the moment...
  does anyone know the keyword for disk usage or network usage?

More specifically, when I go to the preferences window for the indicator I see the following string:
"cpu: {cpu} mem: {mem}"
What do I put in the braces if I want to see I/O or network usage?

EDIT:
I couldn't handle not seeing my network and disk usage so I put together something that will show that along with the cpu. Its one of the answers to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29757/what-can-replace-system-monitoring-in-the-top-gnome-panel-in-unity/37424#37424) question. It will have to do for a half a year until there is a real monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support has been added sometime after the previous answer was added.

Currently my config string is `C: {cpu} | M: {mem} | N:{net}`

Answer (score 5):

The indicator-sysmonitor project is extremely new having first released at the end of March this year.  My recommendation is to create a request on LaunchPad, [here](https://launchpad.net/indicator-sysmonitor), to see if the developers would be interested in adding this capability.

Comment: I couldn't handle not seeing my network and disk usage so I put together something that will show that along with the cpu.  Its one of the answers to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29757/what-can-replace-system-monitoring-in-the-top-gnome-panel-in-unity/37424#37424) question.
It will have to do for a half a year until there is a real monitor.