# Is there a command that returns network utilization?

Tags: software-recommendation, network-monitoring, command-line

I need a command that I can run that returns the current utilization of `wlan0`.

Does such a tool exist? I would prefer something that doesn't require root privileges.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`ifstat` doesnt require root. Run it with `-S` to update the current line instead of printing a new line for each measurement.

```
egil@mutter:~$ ifstat -S
       eth0
 KB/s in  KB/s out
    0.13      0.26
```

Comment: After playing around with some parameters, I got this working. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

bmon runs without root:

[image]

If you give it the right parameters it returns only one line

> bmon -o 'ascii:noheader;quitafter=1' -p wlan0
>   wlan0                         0.00B         0.0      0.00B         0.0

maybe this helps

Answer (score 5):

Try [iftop](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/administration_systeme/iftop)...

but I think that for this you need root privileges.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a shell script that prints a short line with realtime data:

```
#!/bin/bash

ifstat -q -i wlan0 -S 0.1 1 | perl -n -e '/(\d+\.\d+).*(\d+\.\d+)/ && print "Down: $1 KBps - Up: $2 KBps\n"'
```

**Sample Output:**

```
Down: 4.25 KBps - Up: 0.00 KBps
```

*Special thanks to [Egil](https://askubuntu.com/users/13570/egil) for [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37847/is-there-a-command-that-returns-network-utilization/37890#37890) which pointed me to `ifstat`.*

Answer (score 2):

A php soulution similar to the BASH example

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php

define('IFSTAT', '/usr/bin/ifstat');
define('LINK', 'wlan0');

$output = exec(IFSTAT . ' -q -i ' . LINK . ' 0.1 1');

$output = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $output);

echo 'DOWN: ' . str_replace(' ', 'Kbps, UP:', trim($output)) . 'Kbps' . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 2):

vnstat provides daily and monthly RX and TX. No root required.

Install vnstat via synaptic.
Then open a terminal and enter 'vnstat'

Don't be surprised if you don't get any results for the first day or two.
It takes 2-3 days to get results which look like:

```
    rx:  41.61 GiB      tx:  1.84 GiB      total:  43.46 GiB
```

monthly
                     rx      |     tx      |    total    |   avg. rate
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
       Jun '11      3.55 GiB |  167.75 MiB |    3.71 GiB |   12.02 kbit/s
       Jul '11     38.07 GiB |    1.68 GiB |   39.74 GiB |  161.42 kbit/s
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
     estimated     49.36 GiB |    2.17 GiB |   51.54 GiB |

daily
                     rx      |     tx      |    total    |   avg. rate
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
     yesterday      3.35 GiB |  138.04 MiB |    3.48 GiB |  338.34 kbit/s
         today      1.63 GiB |   84.11 MiB |    1.71 GiB |  183.41 kbit/s
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
     estimated      1.80 GiB |      92 MiB |    1.89 GiB |

Answer (score 1):

you can also check network usage/traffic monitor from nethogs.
you can install it by `sudo apt-get install nethogs`.
then launch it as `sudo nethogs <Connection_name>`.

Look at the image for example.

[image]