# Monitor CPU usage in unity

Tags: applet, monitoring, system-monitor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can replace system monitoring in the top Gnome Panel in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29757/what-can-replace-system-monitoring-in-the-top-gnome-panel-in-unity)

Back when I used gnome-panels, I really liked the System Monitor applet. It let me keep an eye on both my processor and bandwidth, it was light, and it was native. Is there a way to achieve this with the current unity interface?

That little graph was useful in many ways. I could spot misbehaving processes, I could tell when a download finished, I could tell when an update finished, etc.

I'm not looking to install screenlets or any fancy stuff, I'm already running Unity 2D because this netbook isn't that tough. I'm looking for something that shows me a little graph of real-time cpu usage (and bandwidth, if possible), it needs to be permanently visible and it needs to be light.