# Unity equivalent to the Gnome 2 system monitor

Tags: unity, gnome-panel, system-monitor, gnome2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can replace system monitoring in the top Gnome Panel in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29757/what-can-replace-system-monitoring-in-the-top-gnome-panel-in-unity)

I'm using gnome 2 right now and looking to switch to unity, but one thing that I really miss is the old gnome 2 system monitor:

[image: The Gnome 2 system monitor]

I found something like this for KDE, but the bars were really thin and didn't give a good idea of the recent history of some system's usage.

**Is there something like this that I can embed in one of the taskbars in Unity?**

**Failing that, is there something like this for any desktop environment other than Gnome 2?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best alternative I know is Indicator Multiload.
The review and installation instructions can be found [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/indicator-multiload-is-a-gnome-applet-style-system-monitor-for-your-desktop-panel/).

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about that one. It's in Oneiric too :)