# Adding a CPU monitor widget in the top corner like in Gnome2

Tags: unity, gnome, monitor, cpu, widgets

I wonder if you can add a widget or something like it in the top corner (next to volume and WiFi and things like that) that displays current use of CPU and maybe RAM. I know you could add stuff like that in Gnome2, altough I can't find a feature like that in Unity or Gnome3.

Comment: are you talking about app indicators? see the system load indicator here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/list-of-application-indicators

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For Gnome Shell:
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/gnome-shell-system-monitor-extension.html

For Unity:
[What can replace system monitoring in the top Gnome Panel in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29757/what-can-replace-system-monitoring-in-the-top-gnome-panel-in-unity)

Comment: You're welcome. You can sign the answer as accepted, so it is not seen as "unanswered".