# How can I restore the activity monitor? 

Tags: 12.04, gui, ram

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can replace system monitoring in the top Gnome Panel in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29757/what-can-replace-system-monitoring-in-the-top-gnome-panel-in-unity)

I was wondering if its still possible to get the Activity Monitor for things like load and ram usage like you used to be able to on 10.04 LTS.

I noticed that all them disappeared after the upgrade to 12.04, now all I get is the File, Edit menu buttons on that bar is there a way to add to this section of the menu bar?

[image: menu bar]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install Indicator Multiload:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:indicator-multiload/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-multiload
```

Network, memory and cpu usage indicator; this is a port of the original System Monitor GNOME Panel applet (gnome-system-monitor applet).

[image]

In `Preferences` you can customize the output to fit it to your desktop theme:

Comment: `E: Invalid operation ppa:indicator-multiload/stable-daily`

Comment: thats strange i have this on my PC!!! and it updated just day before yesterday!!! and now i tried again to add i getting the same error as you
https://launchpad.net/~indicator-multiload/+archive/stable-daily

it says here its available for precise !!!!

Comment: just found my mistake, the command is wrong, updated the thread!
the first command should be sudo add-apt-repository ppa:indicator-multiload/stable-daily