# Passively monitoring CPU activity

Tags: security, monitoring

So everytime I leave my ubuntu desktop alone, it seems that after a while it starts "working on stuff" -- CPU lights lighting, that busy CPU processing sound being pretty loud, etc. But when I move my mouse, it just goes away.

I don't think it's spyware just yet, but, *(puts on tinfoil hat)* is there any way to figure out what kind of processes were running that were taking the most CPU time, and log them historically?

I'm thinking of writing a daemon for monitoring this, actually, but if there's already an existing tool for this, that would be better I guess?

Comment: Running `top` in a terminal (or `htop`, `sudo` apt-get install htop` to install) would be a simple solution for realtime monitoring, there are also a number of indicator applets that will do this on the top panel (see [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/30334/63478) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/29757/63478)). As for your question about logging the info historically, I don't have any immediate ideas--but this is the interesting part of your question and I might suggest making this part of your question more prominent (so your post doesn't get marked as a duplicate).

Comment: What is the "CPU light" and the "busy CPU sound"? If the former is the blue/green/red light on your case/laptop that flickers, it's NOT the CPU but indicates hard disk activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any way to figure out what kind of processes were running that were taking the most CPU time, and log them historically?

Set up a cronjob, running every minute and appending `date` and `ps auxk time | tail -N` to your chosen log file. Set `N` to how many CPU hogs you want logged. Default (without -N) is 10. The total time (in minutes) as of a particular timestamp is the second-last column, in descending order, just before the process name:

```
izx       2096  0.0  0.6 396920  7000 ?        Ssl  16:41   0:11 gnome-session --session=ubuntu
izx       2147  0.0  1.1 681920 11404 ?        Sl   16:41   0:16 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon
izx       2275  0.0  0.8 421544  8684 ?        Sl   16:41   0:16 /usr/lib/bamf/bamfdaemon
izx       2311  0.0  2.8 614148 29388 ?        Sl   16:41   0:16 /usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service
root      1736  0.1  0.2  87632  2576 ?        S    16:41   0:24 /usr/sbin/vmtoolsd
izx       2205  0.1  0.9 446056  9208 ?        Sl   16:41   0:30 /usr/lib/vmware-tools/sbin64/vmtoolsd -n vmusr --blockFd 3
izx       2451  0.3  2.3 551928 24348 ?        Sl   16:41   1:10 gnome-terminal
izx       2163  0.9  6.5 1157128 66616 ?       Sl   16:41   3:39 compiz
root      1058  1.5 15.3 320408 156080 tty7    Ss+  16:41   5:53 /usr/bin/X :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch -background none
izx       2541  2.0 16.1 944464 164536 ?       Sl   16:41   8:03 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
```

You may want to look at `man ps` to clean up the fields you don't need.