# How can I add the current CPU usage to my menu bar as a percentage?

Tags: software-recommendation, cpu, system-monitor

I'm used to OS X and I use [MenuMeters](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/) in my menu bar to monitor CPU usage as a percentage and memory as used/free totals. I really want to add this functionality in Ubuntu as I'm using it for development. I've seen that you can add graphs. Graphs mean nothing to me :). I need percentages. How can I add this functionality in Ubuntu?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this tool guys in Ubuntu 22.04. Caused total freezing. I had to reboot manually and uninstall it from terminal in safe mode. Actually, i tried it twice and happened both times.

Answer (score 96):

There is no need to add any extra repository, just install `indicator-multiload` from the default repos:

```
sudo apt install indicator-multiload
```

Then start it manually the first time by searching for "system load indicator" in the dashboard.

Right click the indicator for preferences.

[image: example]

Comment: its worked for Ubuntu 20.4

Comment: I strongly disrecommend this tool.
It caused video playing stutter on my thinkpad T14s when on battery power, ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Happened to me too, resolved it by logging it from command line and manually removing this. Laptop - Thinkpad P14s

Comment: Avoid this in Ubuntu 22.04. Use TopHat instead (L. Gashi's answer)

Answer (score 91):

The system load indicator can be configured to display numeric values. First make sure that indicator-multiload is installed:

```
sudo apt install indicator-multiload
```

Do the following steps:

1. Search for System Load Indicator in dash and launch it.[image]
2. Right click on the indicator applet and choose Preferences.
   [image]
3. A window will pop up. Click on the **Indicator Items...** button on the lower middle portion of the window.
   [image]
4. Move the item **CPU $(percent(cpu,inuse))** to the top of the list.
   [image]
5. Close all opened windows and notice the numerical CPU load displayed in the panel.
   [image]
6. Note that the entry is customizable. You can get creative and start mixing up different entries. For example, if you want to display memory usage as well, replace the entry with `CPU $(percent(cpu.inuse)) Mem $(size(mem.user))`, which will result in:
   [image]

Comment: If it's possible to fix it somehow? Because when, for example, cpu changes from 9% to 11% (one more digit) entire line is moved. I want labels, like "CPU", "Mem" be static.

Comment: Super great and colorfull

Comment: Note: don't make the system monitor width 800px. It will brick the entire DE. For some reason.

Comment: I strongly disrecommend this tool.
It caused video playing stutter on my thinkpad T14s when on battery power, ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 10):

The "indicator multiload" is the one you are searching for. The commands to install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:indicator-multiload/stable-daily 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install indicator-multiload
```

Read more about it at this link : [webupd8](http://m.webupd8.org/2011/05/network-memory-and-cpu-usage-indicator.html)

**Update:** Now `indicator-multiload` is available in the official PPA as suggested by other answers.
However, if you want the latest version, install it from the PPA `indicator-multiload/stable-daily`.

Comment: I strongly disrecommend this tool.
It caused video playing stutter on my thinkpad T14s when on battery power, ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 6):

For Ubuntu 22.4.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) I can recommend installing TopHat via
`gnome-shell-extension-manager` ([Here](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/07/tophat-system-monitor-gnome-extension) is a installation tutorial).

Installing `indicator-multiload` on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) caused a problem for me. After starting it manually for the first time, going to the preferences and increasing the pixel size my system froze.
I had to shut my system down by holding the power button. After booting the system up again, I could only log into my system but the favourites panel was gone and  I was not able to start a terminal.

If that happens to you you can boot in recovery-mode, uninstall the application and reboot. That fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

Use Gnome shell system monitor extension (works with Ubuntu 18.04LTS too). Install prerequisite:

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gtop-2.0, gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-gst-3.0 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0 chrome-gnome-shell
```

Then visit https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/120/system-monitor/, preferably in Firefox, and install by clicking the toggle button next to the extension's name.

For more info on installation see: https://github.com/paradoxxxzero/gnome-shell-system-monitor-applet

Comment: Appears to not work in 19.04 (installed dependencies but still shows ERROR on going to extensions.gnome.org)

Comment: /!\ these packages could delete gnome-shell (tested on my debian 10)

Answer (score 2):

`indicator-multiload` may have a flickering problem like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409960/app-indicator-top-bar-flickering-22-04), so [tophat](https://github.com/fflewddur/tophat) or [system-monitor-next](https://github.com/mgalgs/gnome-shell-system-monitor-applet) are the better choices (`system-monitor-next` is forked from `gnome-shell-system-monitor`, the original one not under maintenance for a while is not supporting Gnome 42).

Installing the Gnome extension on Ubuntu 22.04,
the most convenient way is using [extension-manager](https://github.com/mjakeman/extension-manager).

Install it `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager`.
Next, run `extension-manager` in the command line or applications.

Answer (score 0):

For Xubuntu, right click on the top panel (the Ubuntu name for a menu bar) and choose Panel | Add New Items | System Load Monitor.  For Unity, see [What can replace system monitoring in the top Gnome Panel in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29757/what-can-replace-system-monitoring-in-the-top-gnome-panel-in-unity) for five different approaches.

Comment: I tried the answers in the question you linked to. I didn't try the long python script, but there's nothing that displays a percentage in the menu bar. All I can get is the graph. Is it that hard to get a percentage? I would think that the graph is harder.