# indicator-multiload - Always display cpu at least 2 digits

Tags: 14.10, indicator

I'm getting a bit seasick with the indicator-mulitload as it constantly cycles between cpu usage less than 10% and greater than 10% which means all the other icons in the tray get pushed back and forth as cpu usage drops in and out of greater or less than 10%.

Is there any way to force the cpu usage to be displayed at at least 2 digits, so 8% would be 08%, as this would stop the icons moving, unless of course it hits 100% but that's so rare I'm not not bothered about taking up the extra space to cover that rarity. I'm happy for it to move everything on that occasion and my guess I'll have more problems anyway if it does as the system will likely keep freezing until cpu cycles drop off again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to specify the `printf` format unfortunately. To always have two digits displayed for CPU usage you need to compile `indicator-multiload` from source.

1. install the build dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install bzr
   sudo apt-get build-dep indicator-multiload
   ```
2. branch the project sources:

   ```
   bzr branch lp:indicator-multiload
   ```
3. Fix the print format for percent data:

   ```
   cd indicator-multiload
   sed -i 's/%u%%/%02u%%/' src/function.vala
   ```
4. Build it:

   ```
   ./autogen.sh && make indicator-multiload
   ```
5. Install the patched indicator in `/usr/local/bin`:

   ```
   sudo cp indicator-multiload /usr/local/bin
   ```

Now below 10%, CPU usage is displayed like this:

[image]

Comment: How do you guys get the indicator to show numbers? Mine just shows graphs. I'd like to have a text label or mouseover on the graph. (15.04)

Comment: you could also add a unicode "WIDE SPACE" to the front, not sure how to actually do it tho

Comment: didnt work in 16.04. compiled without errors, but failed on execution.

Comment: "failed on execution", if  you mean that indicator items don't show up, same results for me. I went back to [0.4](https://launchpad.net/indicator-multiload/stable/0.4/+download/indicator-multiload-0.4.tar.gz) (because seems like indicators were [removed](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~indicator-multiload/indicator-multiload/trunk/revision/137) since). I applied the described fix against that, it works. Requires [this (#138) code fix](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~indicator-multiload/indicator-multiload/trunk/revision/138) (puzzles me how 0.4 was successfully released with that). I'm on 16.04.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind the percentage notation, it's possible to format it to always use 2 decimals places within a [0-1] range:

```
CPU $(decimals(cpu.inuse,2))
```

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/907807) explaining where to use this configuration.