# How can I add the current GPU usage to my menu bar as a percentage?

Tags: software-recommendation, gpu, system-monitor

I used [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/406204/how-can-i-add-the-current-cpu-usage-to-my-menu-bar-as-a-percentage/647060) to add CPU and Mem. and etc usage to my menu par.
is there any way to add GPU usage percentage to my menu bar ??

Comment: I like this extension https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1320/nvidia-gpu-stats-tool/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a question is very (OS version / GPU hardware / graphics driver) specific as solution varies

If you install   https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/120/system-monitor/

there is a GPU setting in Preferences -> DisplayStyle -> both

________________ **Only Nvidia GPUs supported so far** ________________

Currently on 19.04 here is an error with above install here is work around ... download https://github.com/paradoxxxzero/gnome-shell-system-monitor-applet/archive/master.zip

which will give you ~/downloaddir/gnome-shell-system-monitor-applet-master/system-monitor@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com/

```
cp -rp ~/downloaddir/gnome-shell-system-monitor-applet-master/system-monitor@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com  ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
```

so it results in

```
ls -la ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/system-monitor@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com/
```

install upstream packages

```
sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell    
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gtop-2.0 gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0  gir1.2-clutter-1.0
```

to engage issue   alt-F2  then type r in popup

Comment: GPU usage is queried via `nvidia-smi` so I guess this only works for nvidia GPUs?

Comment: yes I updated with Nvidia qualifier