# After updating to ubuntu 22.04, the theme is broken

Tags: gnome, 22.04

I have this after updating to ubuntu gnome 22.04.
[image]

This looks weird when I try adding more opened windows.

Comment: and when you  re-apply a theme what happens?

Comment: No changes, it's still the same.

Comment: Try [Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409960/app-indicator-top-bar-flickering-22-04/1424524#1424524)?