# Ubuntu 22.04 can't see system tray icons such as steam, teams icon

Tags: gnome, unity, icons, 22.04, system-tray

My bottom bar is like this:
[image: Bottom bar]

```
This is session:

        canerveg@canerVegan  ~  loginctl
    SESSION  UID USER     SEAT  TTY 
         29 1000 canerveg seat0 tty2
         c3  118 gdm      seat0 tty1
    
    2 sessions listed.
```

There are no top or side bars.

I have those tweaks extensions:
[image: tweak extensions]

When i disable extensions, I can not still see icons:
[image: when extensions disabled]

This is when i click arrow:
[image: when i click arrow in tray]

What happened to my icons?

Comment: Certainly related to [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409960/app-indicator-top-bar-flickering-22-04/1424524#1424524). Install Unity and life gets easier :)

Comment: If i do `sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop indicator-multiload` and restart, can i revert if something happens?

Comment: From the login screen, you can select Gnome instead of Unity